# RSA secret premaster error

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt

I am having a application which when i run standalone runs well.
This application sends an XML to a server and listens for the reply from that server which is again an XML.This works WELL when running STANDALONE.
But when i run this application inside an web application it gives me follow error:
 **RSA Secret Premaster Error**

I am using apache-tomcat,java-6(GWT).

Can anyone guide me on this issue..Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that this problem happens when your application is establishing an SSL (e.g. HTTPS) connection.  To get more hints to what the root cause is, you need to print the complete stacktrace to see the nested chain.

If you do a Google search for "RSA premaster secret error" you will see lots of forum postings about this.  A common thread of these postings seems to be that some IDE is being used to launch the web server or client, and the IDE is stuffing up the child JVM's bootclasspath in a way that causes the crypto libraries to break.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your comments. You were right this error was getting generated as my tomcat was not configured to handle HTTPS requests.
It is now solved when it was configured to handle HTTPS.

Comment: @Azhar - may I humbly suggest that you click the "tick" mark next to this answer to "accept" it.